# Android SDK, Set ImageView bitmap from URL

Tags: java, android, bitmap

How can I put an image from an url into an `ImageView`?

**i dont want to use any library, id rather stick to the plain old way, i like it. dont judge me. like i said before i got this working but oddly its not anymore**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView damnit = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");

                InputStream in = url.openStream();
                Bitmap bitt = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                damnit.setImageBitmap(bitt);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

**edit!**

Im such an idiot, sorry for taking your time guys... I have to have a runOnUI Thread, and inside have the "damnit.setImageBitmap(bitt);"

Comment: this is a nice exercise, but you really should use a 3rd party library to do this...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get an url from the MainThread. That is not possible. This is the error you will get: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Try to use an `AsyncTask` for example to retrieve an Image from an url.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ImageView damnit = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(damnit);
    downloadTask.execute();
}

class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Bitmap>{
    private ImageView imageView;

    public DownloadTask(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or use a library, for example [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

### How to setup Glide:

build.gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

onCreate:

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load("https://www.some-url.com/image.jpg")
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: nope, still does not work in a new thread, or async task. also i hate using libraries.

Comment: Did you retrieve the bitmap in `doInBackground ` and set the image in `onPostExecute`? See updated answer. Note. I don't judge you by not wanting libraries. In my young days of developing I didn't like it either. After a while I noticed that libraries can really be useful when project are large.

Comment: Well this is not really big at all, and tbh that code there does not work at all. i have no idea what just happened. it was working perfectly before, but i dont know what i did :(

Comment: Did you add the `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` in an (inner) `AsyncTask` class?

Comment: yes, ugh. maybe i should just read the image into a byte array and then decode it and maybe it would work?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Glide Library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the images & set into ImageView:

Why i should recommend the Glide Library?

[Because its very fast & consumes less memory](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en).

Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.

**How to do you Set up Glide:**

Different ways to setup the Glide library to your project

*1.You can download a jar from [GitHub's releases page](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases).*

Or

*2.use Gradle --> build.gradle(Module:app)*

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Or

*3.Use Maven*:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.bumptech.glide</groupId>
  <artifactId>glide</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <version>r7</version>
</dependency>
```

**How do you use Glide?**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView damnit = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    Glide.with(this).load("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png").into(damnit);

    }
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using image library. Try [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) it's an open source library for downloading and caching images from web, it's also easy to use.

Just add this line in dependancies section in gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Then, start to use it like this:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```

**Important note** : avoid to pass empty url to it because it will be throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UrlImageViewHelper library.
get it here-  http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper&a=urlimageviewhelper&v=LATEST

and build a method and use it wherever you want-

```
public void setPicture(Context context, String url, ImageView imageView, int placeholder) {
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imageView, url, placeholder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Universal Image Loader. It is great library. Visit:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader